# Crystal Reports Division Formula Not Calculating as Desired

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am one step away from finishing up a report in Crystal 2008.  I have included a snapshot of the report below.  For some reason I cannot get the formula in the yellow column to calculate correctly.  I am trying to divide the value of Net A for each main data source/year into the yearly Total of Net A to get the % of Data for each Main Data Source.  Net A is pulling from a field in access and the total of Net A is a running total based on a current Run Date using formula `({HNT_End_To_End_Data.REPT_YYMM} = cStr(currentdate,'yyMM')` in the evaluate section of the running total and the field is reset on each change of Year.

The formula in the yellow column is currently `({HNT_End_To_End_Data.Net_A}/Sum ({HNT_End_To_End_Data.Net_A}))*100` and is showing values that are like it's doing NetA divided into the grand total of Net A of all 3 years (3,727,560/108,666,439) rather than the dividing into individual year (3,727,560/34,981,163).  I'm attempting to get the formula to divide each Main Data Source for each year into the yearly Net A total.

I've tried doing many different formulas and have had no luck, so would appreciate any suggestions anyone might have.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a group on `year({sometable.somedate})`? You need to add that group into your aggregate (sum) function:

```
(
 {HNT_End_To_End_Data.Net_A} 
 / 
 Sum({HNT_End_To_End_Data.Net_A}, year({sometable.somedate}))
) * 100
```

**EDIT**: After reviewing the report I can see you are using a conditional formula `{HNT_End_To_End_Data.REPT_YYMM} <> cStr(currentdate,'yyMM')` to suppress the detail section. So `SUM({HNT_End_To_End_Data.Net_A},{HNT_End_To_End_Data.SERVICE_THRU_YEAR})` is actually including the records which aren't being displayed. You have a number of ways to get around this. The simplest is probably to create a new formula for net_a:

```
if {HNT_End_To_End_Data.REPT_YYMM} <> cStr(currentdate,'yyMM') then
 {HNT_End_To_End_Data.Net_A}
else
 0;
```

You can then do:

```
(
 {HNT_End_To_End_Data.Net_A} 
 / 
 Sum({@net_a}, year({sometable.somedate}))
) * 100
```

Comment: I have the report grouped by year. I am using formula `({HNT_End_To_End_Data.Net_A}/(SUM({HNT_End_To_End_Data.Net_A},{HNT_End_To_End_Data.SERVICE_THRU_YEAR}))*100)` but still can't seem to get the correct results.  I have several run dates in my table but the report is only showing the current month.  The formula seems to be dividing Net A for the current month into the total of Net A for the total of all values in the table rather than the current month totals for each year. I have a record selection formula to show only the current run date in the report but the formula isn't doing the same

Comment: Add a column just with ` Sum({HNT_End_To_End_Data.Net_A}, {HNT_End_To_End_D‌​ata.SERVICE_THRU_YEAR})` to understand what that column contains and hopefully why.

Comment: I did as you suggested and the column is returning the total of Net A for all values in the table rather than the total for the current `{HNT_End_To_End_Data.REPT_YYMM}`.  I've tried different things and can't seem to get the total Net A to sum for each year for the current REPT_YYMM.  That's the reason the formula isn't correct, so if I can somehow get this I'd be good.  ;o)

Comment: are you upload the report? i can't think of any scenario where the sum(field, group) function doesn't work properly. there's another horrible solution but i don't want to go down that route.

Comment: I'm sorry Lee but did you mean for me to upload the report?  I didn't quite understand your first sentence and want to be sure. If so where would I upload to?

Comment: yes- sorry was obviously having a bit of a moment! just use a filesharing site or something: http://www.speedyshare.com/ for example

Comment: Ok, I uploaded the draft of my "End_To_End report." The link to the report is [code]http://speedy.sh/5eqXF/End-To-End.rpt[/code].  Would be awesome and much appreciated if you could see where I'm going wrong with calculating the percentage in the % of Data in IRADS column.  The result should be the value of Net A for each Main Data Source for each year divided by the total of Net A for the Year.  Right now it's dividing Net A for the Main Data Source into the total of Net A for the 3 years in the report rather than the individual year. Maybe it's my grouping or something? Thanks so much!

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!  You're suggestion worked out and the results are now what they should be!  You've been a great help!  Appreciate it!  =D